# not able to configure AzureDevops service webhook with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build, triggers, devops, hook

I had created 1 pipeline for.net application which will build and deploy the package to iis now I want to set a trigger that when code is committed on Azure repos the Jenkins build it automatically when I am configuring it is saying Jenkins query failed with exception 'Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.i am using Jenkins webhook   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yQAa.png)

i had tried to delte api token and genrate new one
i had checked the plugin required for webhook trigger